Apache Camel unit test in Spring Boot
I am snew to Apache Camel and the concepts of unit testing are still a bit confusing for me.
In my Spring Boot application I have a simple RouteBuilder:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Autowired})
public class PollApiRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  private final LastRequestTimeRepository repository;
  private final TokenService tokenService;

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer:poll?period=10000") // Trigger every 10 seconds (for testing)
      .id("pollApiTimer")
      .bean(tokenService, "getToken")
      .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Bearer ${body}"))
      .bean(repository, "getNextTimeRange")
      .to("direct:fetchMessages");
  }
}

After studying many examples I came up with two alternative unit tests
Using @SprigBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"camel.main.java-routes-include-pattern=**//routes/PollApiRoute"})
@MockEndpoints // Mock endpoints used in the route
public class PollApiRouteTest {

  public static final String TEST_TOKEN = "your-test-token";

  @Autowired
  CamelContext context;

  @EndpointInject("mock:direct:fetchMessages") // Mock the endpoint where the route sends data
  private MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

  @MockBean
  private LastRequestTimeRepository lastRequestTimeRepository;

  @MockBean
  private TokenService tokenService;

  @Test
  public void shouldSetAuthorizationAndTimeRange() throws InterruptedException {
// Arrange
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange(now.minus(Duration.ofHours(24)), now);
    when(lastRequestTimeRepository.getNextTimeRange()).thenReturn(timeRange);
    when(tokenService.getToken()).thenReturn(TEST_TOKEN);

    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(timeRange);
    resultEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("Authorization", "Bearer " + TEST_TOKEN);

// Act
// Triggered automatically by timer

// Assert
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}

And using CamelTestSupport
@CamelSpringBootTest
public class PollApiRouteNewTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  public static final String TEST_TOKEN = "your-test-token";

  @Produce("direct:start")
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @EndpointInject("mock:direct:fetchMessages")
  private MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

  @MockBean
  private LastRequestTimeRepository lastRequestTimeRepository;

  @MockBean
  private TokenService tokenService;

  @Override
  protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

    return new PollApiRoute(lastRequestTimeRepository, tokenService);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
  }

  @Test
  // Automatically mock the endpoint
  public void shouldSetAuthorizationAndTimeRange() throws Exception {

    // Arrange
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange(now.minus(Duration.ofHours(24)), now);
    when(lastRequestTimeRepository.getNextTimeRange()).thenReturn(timeRange);
    when(tokenService.getToken()).thenReturn(TEST_TOKEN);

    // Add mock endpoint
    adviceWith(context, "pollApiTimer", a -> {
      a.replaceFromWith("direct:start");
      a.mockEndpointsAndSkip("direct:fetchMessages");
    });

    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(timeRange);
    resultEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("Authorization", "Bearer " + TEST_TOKEN);
    context.start();

// Act
    producerTemplate.sendBody("");

// Assert
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}

Both the tests work but I am not completely satisfied with either of them. On the first one I do not like that it depends on the timer.
As for the second one I tried to use @UseAdviceWith annotation insttead of overriding isUseAdviceWith method and @MockEndpoints instead of mockEndpointsAndSkip in adviceWith. But I was not successful.
Can anyone tell me whish of thouse aproaches are bettor and/or tell me how can I improve it  (or do it in a completely different way)?

For the first case you could also use the advice and replace the from endpoint. Then you're not using the timer. Personally I'm using the advice approach to test the flow of the route itself, combined with sometimes setting headers manually if needed. For transformation you can use the route itself or just write vanilla unit tests, without camel test framework at all. For your second test, your missing the leading mock: I think. You can also get the endpoint uri by the object itself, instead of using a string.
